# SQL Trigger Works in Play but not Production

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I created an SQL trigger in my Play database and it worked great.  When I moved it over to Production, it suddenly won't work.  We want the trigger to kick off whenever someone edits one of two custom fields in our database.  The company who created the software already set up a trigger that kicks of any time a change is made to the database object (it just didn't track the changes made to custom fields).  If I let my new trigger create a new record, I wound up with two audit records, so I changed my trigger to update the audit record the software company's trigger created.  Could anyone tell me what I have done wrong?  Here is my trigger:

```
USE [TmsEPrd]
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[tr_Biograph_Udef_Audit_tracking]    Script Date: 11/23/2020 10:22:57 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_Biograph_Udef_Audit_tracking] ON [dbo].[BIOGRAPH_MASTER] FOR UPDATE AS
BEGIN


IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM deleted d
             JOIN inserted i ON d.ID_NUM = i.ID_NUM
             JOIN (SELECT ID_NUM, binary_checksum(UDEF_10A_1, UDEF_2A_4) AS inserted_checksum 
                FROM inserted) a ON i.ID_NUM = a.ID_NUM
             JOIN (SELECT ID_NUM, binary_checksum(UDEF_10A_1, UDEF_2A_4) AS deleted_checksum 
                FROM deleted) b ON d.ID_NUM = b.ID_NUM
            WHERE a.inserted_checksum <> b.deleted_checksum)
    BEGIN    
    Update BIOGRAPH_HISTORY
    set archive_job_name = 'UDEF_Change',
    udef_2a_4 = i.udef_2a_4,
    udef_2a_4_CHG = i.udef_2a_4_chg,
    udef_10a_1 = i.udef_10a_1,
    udef_10a_1_chg = i.udef_10a_1_chg
    from 
    (select i.ID_NUM, SYSDATETIME()as job_time_a, 
    i.UDEF_10A_1, case when i.UDEF_10A_1 = d.UDEF_10A_1 then 0 when i.UDEF_10A_1 is null and d.UDEF_10A_1 is null then 0 else 1 end as UDEF_10A_1_CHG,
    i.UDEF_2A_4, case when i.UDEF_2A_4 = d.UDEF_2A_4 then 0 when i.UDEF_2A_4 is null and d.UDEF_2A_4 is null then 0 else 1 end as UDEF_2A_4_CHG,
    d.USER_NAME,d.JOB_NAME,d.JOB_TIME
    FROM deleted d JOIN inserted i ON d.ID_NUM = i.ID_NUM) i
    join BIOGRAPH_HISTORY b on i.ID_NUM = b.ID_NUM
    where DATEDIFF(Minute, i.job_time_a, b.ARCHIVE_JOB_TIM) = 0
        and b.ARCHIVE_JOB_NAME not like 'UDEF_Change%'
    END;    
END;
```

Comment: Are you saying there is already a trigger on this table, and you added your own?

Comment: Why all those `JOIN`s to `inserted` and `deleted` in the `EXISTS`? What's wrong with just  `WHERE binary_checksum(i.UDEF_10A_1, i.UDEF_2A_4) <> binary_checksum(d.UDEF_10A_1, d.UDEF_2A_4)`?

Answer (score 1):

Try specifying @order = 'LAST' for your trigger.  It might be that your trigger is executing first and not finding a record to update.  In your test system, the trigger execution order might be reversed.

The order that triggers are created might affect trigger execution order, but this is not something to rely upon.  When you think about it, this can be a headache.  A test system that looks just like production can behave differently.

This is similar to relying upon a "natural" record order of a clustered index and not using a ORDER BY clause.  A different execution plan can use a different index or go parallel resulting in a different or no order.